# hist column in dependency of the relative frequency of other column (R)

Tags: r, histogram

Lets say we have the table:

```
x  y  
1  43
1  54
2  54   
3  22
2  22
1  43
```

I want to hist on the x-axis only 1,2,3 so it recognizes the unique values but in addition it should show in % the frequency of the number 43 in 1 then 54 and so on. Should both columns be factorized?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes thats that one. How do I tell now to give me the relative frequency on the y axis?

Comment: Refer to my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")
library("tidyr")

df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,3,2,1), y = c(43,54,54,22,22,43))

#Creating a counter that will keep track
#Of how many of each number in y exist for each x category
df$n <- 1
df %<>% #This is a bidirectional pipe here that overwrites 'df' with the result!
  group_by(x, y) %>% #Unidirectional pipe
  tally(n) %>%
  mutate(n = round(n/sum(n), 2)) #Calculating as percentage

#Plotting
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = as.factor(y), y = n, x = x)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(y = "Percentage contribution from each y category") + 
  #Adding the percentage values as labels
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(n*100,"%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2)
```

[image: stackedbarplot.png]

**Note**: the y-axis values are presented as percentages because `position="fill"` is passed to `geom_bar()`.

Comment: Do you know how to show the percentage on the corresponding "stack".

Comment: It would be really great and helpful if you could help me with the last step. I would give you the green checkmark

Comment: @Textime please see the updated answer. Is this what you were looking for?